# How to strech Visual assets in UWP?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, assets, stretching

I have generated the assets for my uwp app using the `Assets Generator` (which is inside the `Package.appxmanifest`) and also using [this extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shenchauhan.UWPTileGenerator). 
It generates files OK. However when i see the icons, they are centered. Like [image: this] (the icon on the right of Settings) where you can barely see anything. The quality of the icon is better than it is showed here, and the quality of the icon is good. So the problem is that the icon is centered in the rectangle. I want it to stretch over all its rectangle.
Like:[image: this]. (it does not need to stretch to 2 rectangles as in this photo.)

How can i do this?

Edit: Perhaps the question was not clear. I want to remove the padding from the icon. Let me give you another example that may be more clear. In the taskbar.
[image]
I have my logo here, with padding outside. I want it to stretch so there is no padding.I want my logo to be the size of the actual container.

Answer (score 1):

Stretching the icon to 2 rectangles has nothing to do with the developer. You as a developer do not have any control over that. The user can right click the tiles and select the size of the tile, if they select it to be medium size, it will take space of 2 rectangles if small then only 1 and if large size is selected it take size of 4 rectangles.

> In the image below you can see I have opened the context menu on the S**Microsoft Store** tile and its selected size is currently **Wide** which is why it is currently taking 2 squares ( or rectangles ) and I can change its size to small, Medium or Large as well, this is all done at the user end after they have installed your app.

[image: sample image]

> **If you want to remove extra padding around your assets**: when you generate assets with the built in asset generator of the manifest there is a checkbox "add recommended padding" uncheck it and you will have the desired result.

Comment: You did not understand my question. Please see my edit

Comment: @KristjanKica when you generate assets with the built in asset generator of the manifest there is a checkbox "add recommended padding" uncheck it and you will have the desired result.

Comment: I have fixed that, already, thanks. The problem is the icon on taskbar.

Comment: good to know tht you fixed that, and about the taskbar, do you mean you do not want the bckground theme color on your icon? and you want the icon exactly like you have shown visual studio icon in your image?

Comment: no, i can fix the background by using a transparent image.I wanted to remove the padding. The same as what unchecking the checkbox does for other assets

Comment: That is a built-in padding that all icons in the taskbar have and you can't remove it.